# how to make a build failed in hudson using batch command

Tags: windows, build, batch-file, hudson, command

Im using Hudson for our HTML build main reason for using CI is to validate the html files during each files with cse validator. For validating the HTML I have used the following code

```
@echo off

PUSHD "F:\Solutions\Documents\Design\html\ValTest"
For %%X in (*.html) do (
"C:\Program Files\HTMLValidator100\cmdlineprocessor"  -outputfile output.txt   -r1 %%X
set HTMLVAL_ERROR=%ERRORLEVEL%
type output.txt >> result.txt
)

    set ERRORLEVEL=%HTMLVAL_ERROR%

POPD
```

Validation process is working fine but even there is an error in the HTML file hudson is not triggering the build as failed, its always Success.

Please let me know how can I trigger the build failure from batch command.

Answer (score 0):

You should use exit command :

```
@echo off

PUSHD "F:\Solutions\Documents\Design\html\ValTest" For %%X in (*.html) do ( "C:\Program Files\HTMLValidator100\cmdlineprocessor" -outputfile output.txt -r1 %%X set HTMLVAL_ERROR=%ERRORLEVEL% type output.txt >> result.txt )

POPD

exit %HTMLVAL_ERROR%
```

which sets the error level of the whole batch.

Comment: But still its success and the output file is showing 1 errors in the file, there are three html files and result of one is CSE HTML Validator Professional v10.01 (Unregistered)
Checking "test.html" (16447 characters).
File date is Tuesday, December 07, 2010 at 11:26:37 AM.
File checked on Friday, February 18, 2011 at 10:31:33 AM.
Number of lines checked: 68 in 0.00 seconds
Number of programs run: 168,Number of end tags: 59 (73.8% of start tags with end tags), Number of messages: 16, Number of errors: 1 (first in line 68),Number of warnings: 20 (first in line 2) almost same for other two files

Comment: If you try to do a simple windows batch in hudson : exit 1. You will see it makes the job fails. So my guess is that your HTMLVAL_ERROR is not set correctly. Maybe due to the loop, it takes only the error value for the last html file, so if the last file succeed...

Comment: All the html file has validation errors, but it still has the value 0 for the errorlevel,